# How to reload preferences without restarting?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Every time after saving preferences, they won't take effect immediately, I have to restart the player, is there a way to reload the preferences without restarting?

VLC: v3.0.16
OS: Windows 10

Comment: It's designed that way. It's the same on Mac & always has been.

Comment: @Tetsujin The most confusing thing is it doesn't even notify the user to reload VLC for changes to take effect, so I always thought it was a bug.

Comment: VLC is an app built by committee. Different people take on different aspects of it, different people write the Win, nix & Mac implementations. To get this fixed you'd need to interest one of the devs sufficiently to take on the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tried editing and saving preferences on multiple Windows computers, they all required reloading VLC to take effect.